# What's the technology that Gravatar uses to resize our images when we upload them?

Tags: gravatar, image-manipulation

What's the technology that Gravatar uses for us to resize our images when we upload it?

Is it using the HTML5 Canvas API through JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it's just js. Unless they are doing Agile for their front-end and already went through another cycle. I remember looking at it when I was doing Wordpress stuff a couple of years back.

Edit to answer question: No, I don't think you need the canvas element unless they have significantly changed their code-base in the last year.

Comment: is canvas required for that technology?

Answer (score 3):

I would think it's [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Gravatar has been around for quite a while.

Comment: i don't get you.. the technology used simply had to be javascript right?  i mean I know that It is javascript but I do not know if it is simply javascript or javascript with canvas..